# Single quotation marks as arguments to a Java program

Tags: java, args, quotation-marks

When I run my jar from the cmd in this way:

```sh
java -jar myapp.jar -fn='Something'
```

I get `args = [-fn=Something]`. So, the problem is that it misses the quotation marks. The same happens with the double quotation marks.

What can I do to solve this? I couldn't find any solution on the Internet.

P.S. another question would be if I can make my program recognize automatically the -fn variable or I just should parse it like a String. I am using the parsing method, but I just want to know if maybe there are other (more ethical) ways.

Comment: Escape the single quotes using backslash like - `\'Something\'` and give it a try.

Comment: Is this the only solution?

Comment: @RaduAramă This is an issue with the shell you are using, not with java. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-and-quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways to solve the quotes problem:

with escaping the quote:

```java
java -jar myapp.jar -fn="\'Something\'"
java -jar myapp.jar -fn="\"Something\""
```

with single and double quotes:

```java
java -jar myapp.jar -fn='"Something"'
```

If you want to create a console programme, I can recommend [Picocli](https://www.baeldung.com/java-picocli-create-command-line-program) or [Spring Shell](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-shell-cli). Otherwise, you could use e.g. the [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) to parse the arguments, or you can do it yourself manually.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.
I just had a specific task to make the program to take specifically these types of inputs like -fn='Something'
But I think it was a mistake

Comment: Picocli (https://picocli.info) can be used to create both interactive shell programs as well as simple CLI commands (with subcommands, colors and autocompletion). Not sure if Commons CLI should be recommended. :-) (But I’m biased...) :-)